# Backbone Routers: wait for data to be fetched first

Tags: routes, logic, backbone.js

I think I don’t quite get the idea behind the proper usage of Backbone routers. Here’s what I’ve got:

I have some data that I fetch from the server when the page loads and then pack it into models and collections. The number of those models and collections is indefinite. I want to use the router to be able to render the certain collection’s view directly from the start.

The problem is: Backbone router starts up early, and since I ask it to access a certain view and trigger its `render` action, it cannot do that, because those views are not yet created. That means I actually have to make my routes start up after the fetch is complete.

I don’t know if this is a proper way to do it, but the only idea I came up with is to:

1. Wrap the routes definition and the `Backbone.history.start();` bit into a separate top-level-accesible function (i.e. prepare to call it manually later on).
2. Run that function as the `success` callback for my collections’s `fetch()`
3. The number of those collections is unknown, also I have no way to find out when all of them have been fetched, and I don’t want to start the routes more than once. So I make use of `_.defer()` and `_.once()`.

This works, but it sure looks very weird:

Routers:

```
    window.startRoutes = _.once(function() {

        var AccountPage = Backbone.Router.extend({

          routes: {
            'set/:id': 'renderSet',
          },

          renderSet: function(setId) {

              /** … **/

              // Call the rendering method on the respective CardView
              CardsViews[setId].render();

          }

        });

        var AccountPageRouter = new AccountPage;

        Backbone.history.start();

    });
```

Collection:

```
window.CardsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Card,

    initialize: function(params) {

        /** … **/

        // Get the initial data
        this.fetch({success: function() {
            _.defer(startRoutes);
        }});

    },

});
```

So my question is… am I doing it right? Or is there a better way to do this (must be)?

Comment: Why make an ajax call immediately?  Why not simply render the page with the json required for initial databload and pass the data into backbone start?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can define your router ahead of time; it won't do anything until you call Backbone.History.start().

You can bind the "reset" event on your collection to start history like this:

```
my_collection.bind("reset", _.once(Backbone.History.start, Backbone.History))
```

Then the router will start doing stuff when your collection is fully loaded. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for (since you mentioned having a variable number of collections).

I have a similar situation, except that I know in advance which collections I want to have loaded before I start routing. I added a startAfter method to my Router, like so:

```
  window.Workspace = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
    . . .
    startAfter: function(collections) {
      // Start history when required collections are loaded
      var start = _.after(collections.length, _.once(function(){
        Backbone.history.start()
      }))
      _.each(collections, function(collection) {
        collection.bind('reset', start, Backbone.history)
      });
    }
  }));
```

and then after I've setup my collections

```
  Workspace.startAfter([collection_a, collection_b, ...])
```

This could be adapted to work with standalone models too, although I think you'd need to bind to something other than the 'reset' event.

I'm glad I read your example code, the use of _.once and _.defer pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Isn't it `my_collection.bind("reset", _.once(Backbone.history.start))`?

Comment: You used wrong arguments for `_.once()`. I will edit your answer to fix this. kthxbye :)

Comment: The `_.once()` example didn't work for me. I had to use:

    `app.users.on("reset", _.once(function () {
        Backbone.history.start();
    }));`

Answer (score 1):

I'm just checking in my `.render()` method that all required fields are filled, before using it. If it's not filled yet - i'm rendering an '*Loading...*' widget.

And all my views are subscribed to model changes, by `this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);`, so just after model will be loaded, `render()` will be called again.